# Simulate obstacles in logical matrix

Tags: matlab, math

I'm writing an optimal path planning algorithm for one of my projects, and am a bit stuck on how to generate the map. In order to test my algorithm, I want to generate random maps that the object will pass through with obstacles in the way. To generate the maps I am making a logical array with "1" for wall or obstacle and "0" when there is nothing in the way. I am having some issues placing the obstacles however.

For now, this is what I've written in MATLAB (though I think the core idea can be solved in any language):

```
%     lenx = length in x-direction of map [m]
%     leny = length in y-direction of map [m]
%     numObs = number of obstacles
%     obsLoc = 2D array with the central location(s) of the obstacle(s)
%       [x1, y1; x2 y2; ...]
%     obsSize = size of the obstacles (all same size) [m]
%               assume the obstacles are square.
%     res = resolution of the map [cell/m]
%     
% Outputs:
%     map = 2D logical array which translates into a map
%
%---------------------------------------------------------
function map = createMap(lenx, leny, numObs, obsLoc, obsSize, res)
    %Making map of the given size
    map = zeros(leny*res, lenx*res);
    
    %Adding walls
    map(:,1) = 1;
    map(:, lenx*res) = 1;
    map(1,:) = 1;
    map(leny*res, :) = 1;
    
    %Recalculating obstacle size for this grid
    obsSize = obsSize - 1;
    %Adding obstacles
    for i = 1:1:numObs
        map(obsLoc(i,1)*res-obsSize*res:obsLoc(i,1)*res+obsSize*res,...
            obsLoc(i,2)*res-obsSize*res:obsLoc(i,2)*res+obsSize*res) = 1;
    end

end
```

The obsSize parameter is representing the dimension of one of the sides of the square obstacle. Here is a sample solution I ran:

```
>> createMap(10,10,1,[5,5],1,1)

ans =

     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

Looks good! But the issue begins for obstacle sizes and resolutions that are not 1 or 2...

```
>> createMap(10,10,1,[5,5],0.5,2)

ans =

     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1

>> createMap(10,10,1,[5,5],3,2)

ans =

     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1
     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

For the first one, we would expect there to be a 1 somewhere close to the middle, but it's nowhere to be found. In the second one, we'd expect to find 6 ones in each direction (3m * 3cell/m = 6 cell), but we are getting 8 (It's also possible that this is not what my code is calculating, but this is what I'm hoping it does. Neither case is working, and I think it has to do with this line:

```
Recalculating obstacle size for this grid
    obsSize = obsSize - 1;
```

I'm pretty sure I do have to recalculate the object size so it fits to the grid, but how can I do this for any grid and obstacle? Is there a way to scale that "-1" such that it acts according to the size of the grid/obstacle?

Let me know what you come up with, and if there's any other glaring issues in my code?

Thanks!

Comment: The side length of the obstacle should depend on the variable res, because the map scales as res changes. Thus, the line you pointed out should be changed to obsSize = obsSize * res.